# Issues updating record with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having one-to-many relationship tables. When I insert records, the program inserts new records without any problem, but when I try to update the record by using `saveOrUpdate()`, the program does not work as my expectation. Only parent table (e.g., `student`) record is updated and new records inserted in the child table (e.g., `studentaddress`). As in the parent table, I need an update in child table too.

How to achieve this? Please help me. Following is the Hibernate tool-generated code:

**Student Table**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

**Studentaddress Table**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
```

I have searched a lot but could not get any site relating to update but I have seen some sites for one table update. In my case, I want to update two tables.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to student this

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
```